# how to download a CVS reposititory from sourceforge

Tags: java, programming, git, source-code, version-control

How do I download this code with cvs?  I press "enter" when prompted for a password, but no download initiates.

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/jamochamud login 
Logging in to :pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:2401/cvsroot/jamochamud
CVS password: 
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ cvs --version

Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13-MirDebian-11 (client/server)

Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Portions contributed by Thorsten Glaser for the MirOS Project.
Senior active maintainers include Larry Jones, Derek R. Price,
and Mark D. Baushke.  Please see the AUTHORS and README files from the CVS
distribution kit for a complete list of contributors and copyrights.

CVS may be copied only under the terms of the GNU General Public License,
a copy of which can be found with the CVS distribution kit.

Specify the --help option for further information about CVS
thufir@mordor:~$
```

I should be able to download as so:

> Anonymous CVS Access
>
> This project's SourceForge.net CVS repository can be checked out
>   through anonymous (pserver) CVS with the following instruction set.
>   The module you wish to check out must be specified as the modulename.
>   When prompted for a password for anonymous, simply press the Enter
>   key. To determine the names of the modules created by this project,
>   you may examine their CVS repository via the provided web-based CVS
>   repository viewer.
>
> cvs
>   -d:pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/jamochamud
>   login

https://sourceforge.net/p/jamochamud/code/?source=navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had thought that cvs repositories had all gone but this one works well enough with the following commands:

1. If you do not have a `$HOME/.cvspass` file in place already use the following command:

   ```
   touch $HOME/.cvspass
   ```
2. Login as you have previously done and use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as the password:

   ```
   cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/jamochamud login
   ```
3. Download the required module, I have selected what I believe is the most appropriate one but there are [a few choices](http://jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jamochamud/). Try this:

   ```
   cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/jamochamud co -P JamochaMUD/
   ```

   You can manually use `extranet/`, `gui/` and `utils/` as module names.
4. You can download all of the modules and in fact the entire repository  (and I suspect that this not what you really want) with this:

   ```
   cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@jamochamud.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/jamochamud co -P .
   ```

   Don't miss the dot on the end as this is crucial for this command.

All worked fine on my system and hopefully on yours as well :)

Answer (score 2):

After you have logged in:

```
cvs checkout [repository]
```

Comment: what do I set for `CVSROOT`?  I get `export CVSROOT=/home/thufir/NetbeansProjects` gives `cvs [checkout aborted]: /home/thufir/NetbeansProjects/CVSROOT: No such file or directory`